# Downloading file in Android browser data transfer failed

Tags: php, android, apache, centos

We've been searching for the cause of this issue for a few days now so maybe somebody has some insight.

We're using php to force a download of files (in this case mp3) from the server into PC browsers and Android devices. The code works fine on PC. On ALL Android devices we've tested, the GET request will trigger the download manager to attempt to get the file, but Android won't respect the attached filename, instead showing the name of the script, and the file download will ultimately fail with the following message:

> Download Failed - Data connection failed

Attempting to download the file from a test site running on my computer with the EXACT same code works correctly.

I created a brand new server yesterday with the exact same operating system (CentOS) and version of PHP (5.5.16), dropped my php script onto that box and attempted again from my Android device and it WORKED perfectly. Again, EXACT same php code.

All signs are pointing to the answer being a server (mis)configuration problem. I didn't set up this server, nor do I have root access, so my testing options have been limited to trying to get my sandbox servers to "break" and start reproducing the same behavior.

I'd include PHP code, but I have 2 separate environments where the code works fine. If I run dev tools in my desktop browser against the working and non-working environments and compare responses, they are identical from what I can tell. The headers are identical and the payload is the exact same size. *Something* is causing Android to not like the response from one server, and like the response from the other.

Some insight, or at least a place to start would be helpful. The only two things that *are* different between my environments are:

- Working sandbox environment is responding with HTTP 1.0 and the SSL
  cert is from Rapid SSL. The sandbox environment will work with or without SSL turned on.
- Non-working staging/production environments are responding with HTTP
  1.1 and the SSL cert is a wildcard cert from COMODO.

I wish I could be more helpful but I've exhausted the usual, obvious questions that responders would ask on here. If you need more info, or want to see phpinfo dumps, I can provide.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

EDIT - The Android request are showing in the access logs and there are no errors. From a server log perspective, everything looks perfect.